# Как сделать чтобы exe не банился антивирусом при запуске

Tags: c++, exe

Создал прогу, обычное консольное окно, у меня оно нормально запускается, но если перекинуть на другой комп, то антивирус даже не дает его запустить, причем другие не подписанные ехе с левых сайтов нормально запускаются, что нужно сделать чтобы антивирус не блочил прогу?

В общем код проги такой=)

```
#include <iostream>

void main(){
    system("pause");
}
```

сам exe https://yadi.sk/d/xlOGwNKLgVfq2

ругается на него аваст и вин 8, получает люди из инета, если запускать с флешки то все нормально, если проверить антивирусом файл на флешке то тоже все нормально

Вот и  virustotal
https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/315ad13da888bb4aa6a88dd8bde3fba811f7384746f70bcca80ed630a309ca8c/analysis/1431032185/

Comment: Каким образом прога попадает на другой компьютер? Случайно не с флешке запускается?

Comment: В общем, обсуждение сферического случая в вакууме. Результат проверки вашего файла на virustotal (точнее ссылка на него) крайне приветствуется.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, какой антивирус вы имеете ввиду.
Есть, например, Windows 8 Smart Screen, который блочит любые приложения, даже подписанные сертификатом (но не блочит подписанные спец ключом), пока их не скачает какое-то количество пользователей.
Наверно и другие антивирусы тоже могут действовать на основе популярности программы у других пользователей.

У меня подписанное обычным сертификатом приложение ( я его получил бесплатно как опен-сурс разработчик). Через некоторое время этот сертификат попал в белый список майкрософт и SmartScreen перестал жаловаться на новые версии приложения. Это произошло где-то через месяц, после того как я начал подписывать, скачиваний у меня гдето 5 тысяч.

Comment: А как подписать exe этим ключом, и какое примерное количество скачиваний должно быть?

Comment: Этот ключ так просто не получить, он покупается за деньги у майкрософт и распространяется, если не ошибаюсь, как usb  устройство,

Comment: неужели все мелкие проги которые я скачиваю имеют этот ключ? дупустим есть игра марио портал у неё даже цифровой подписи нету, а ключ чтоли купили? Может нужно при компиляции этого самого exe что-то писать?

Comment: @Kopkan, поймите что вы столкнулись с ложным срабатыванием. И наиболее правильный способ его не иметь - обратиться к вендору, который срабатывает. На других файлах нет срабатывания не потому что у них волшебный ключ, а потому что это другие файлы.

Comment: Через некоторое время/количество скачиваний (не знаю сколько) Smart Screen перестает жаловаться на приложение, даже неподписанное.

И все же я немного неточен в ответе, у меня подписанное обычным сертификатом приложение ( я его получил бесплатно как опен-сурс разработчик). Через некоторое время этот сертификат попал в белый список майкрософт и SmartScreen перестал жаловаться на новые версии приложения. Это произошло где-то через месяц, после того как я начал подписывать, скачиваний у меня гдето 10 тысяч.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , на все мои файлы, которые я компилю в своей вижул студио такая хрень, как мне быть то?)

Comment: @Kopkan я вам и в третий раз напишу: обращайтесь к производителю антивируса.

Comment: @zenden2k, а как скачивания(запуски) то как набрались если Smart Screen не дает exe запустить, это получается пользователю нужно сначала его отключить а потом только запускать приложение, это бред же какой-то)

Comment: @Kopkan, там можно нажать "Подробнее" 
http://goo.gl/yJZhyV
http://goo.gl/njJ9PT

Comment: @zenden2k, после пропадания предупреждения от Smart Screen, в хроме файлы тоже перестали предупреждения выбивать? И в свойствах exe можно ли увидеть есть ли ключ майкрософт в нем?

Comment: @Kopkan,  Хром у меня даже на прогу автора не жалуется. Какой еще ключ майкрософт? Кроме моего сертификата, там ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если антивирус определяет вашу программу как потенциально вредоносную:

Во-первых, вам следует по возможности избавиться от всего того, что антивирусы не любят: сжатие исполняемых файлов, особенно экзотическими упаковщиками; общесистемные хуки и т. п.

Во-вторых, надо пойти на сайт производителя антивируса и найти форму для отправки сообщения о ложной тревоге.

В-третьих, можете попробовать обзавестись качественной цифровой подписью, чтобы убедить антивирус, чтобы вы доблестный автор ПО, подтвердивший свою личность.

Comment: Но прога прога просто пустое консольное окно...=(

Comment: @Kopkan На чём написано приложение? Это просто запущенный "шаблон", или вы добавили какой-то код? У вас нет на файлах метки URL-зоны? Вы уверены, что вас блокирует антивирус?

Comment: Может имеется ввиду Windows 8 Smart Screen?

Comment: О добыче столь хорошего сертификата можно забыть раз и навсегда, сертификат который может получить любой встречный за определенную мзду никогда не будет пропуском через АВ.

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема конкретного антивируса. Если у него нету возможности добавить каталог, в котором вы программируете, в список исключений — выбросьте антивирус на помойку. Если антивирус поставили вам ваши админы на работе, поговорите с ними.

Если проблема на машине у клиента, тут хуже. Вам придётся отписаться в их техническую поддержку.

В любом случае, это не программистская, а организационная проблема. Если ваш код не содержит вирусов, он не должен блокироваться антивирусом, точка.

Answer (score 0):

Обращайтесь к производителю срабатывающего антивируса, пускай исправляют ложное срабатывание.